# Dynamically changed disabledTime in Jquery timepicker

Tags: jquery, timepicker

I would like to change disabledTime in Jquery Timepicker. When user select a date in datepicker the disabled time value in timepicker have to be changed. But it isn`t working fine.

HTML code

```
<label>Date:</label>
<input type="text" id="datepicker"/>
<label>Time: </label>
<input type="text" id="timepicker"/>
```

JS code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
            minDate: 0,
            onSelect: function(dateText) {
                var disabledTime = [['13:00', '18:00'], ['19:00', '20:00']];
                $('#timepicker').datepicker('option', 'disableTimeRanges', disabledTime);
            }
        });
        var disabledTime = [['15:00', '16:00']];
        $('#timepicker').timepicker({
            'minTime': '10:00',
            'maxTime': '22:00',
            'showDuration': true,
            'timeFormat': 'H:i',
            'show2400': true,
            'step': 60,
            'disableTimeRanges' : disabledTime
        });
    });
```

For the first time, when the document is ready, disabling time works fine, but then it doest not.

Comment: timepicker is a jquery plugin? if so, specify which one you're using

Comment: why do you use `$('#timepicker').datepicker(...` inside the onSelect action of datepicker? It shouldn't be `$('#timepicker').timepicker(...` instead?

Comment: Change the line `$('#timepicker').datepicker('option', 'disableTimeRanges', disabledTime);` with this one: `$('#timepicker').timepicker('option', 'disableTimeRanges', disabledTime);`. Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/yh3u387p/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really, my mistake. I was using another function to range timepicker and didn`t see that now i am using "datepicker". Thanks [@leo_ap](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1644937/leo-ap) and [@ndreivictor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1135971/andreivictor) for help.